# What word means "the top of a person's head"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing something—a story to be exact—and I am looking for a word which means "the top of a person's head." I remember seeing a word in which its meaning is exactly this one from a book that I'd read—*Crispin: The Cross of Lead*. I think it was something like "tope", but I looked at its meaning and it did not match.

Can anyone help me? I don't have the book with me because I just borrowed it at my previous school.

Comment: There really isn't a word in common use - I think most people would just say "the top of the head".  And I think the word you remember might be "toupée" (from French, hence the accent), which is a small wig intended to cover the bare part of the scalp in male pattern baldness.

Comment: @EricDuminil Just looked at its meaning, and it is "the skin on top of one's head where hair grows." It is near, but not close enough to be defined as the top of a person's head.

Comment: If you're thinking of "tope"; the brimless cylindrical chef hat is a "toque", and the haircut of a medieval friar (as well as the resulting bald spot on top) is a "tonsure".

Comment: I suspect that user662852's answer below correctly identifies the term used in the book you mention. From page 310 of [_The Cross of Lead_](https://books.google.com/books?id=je-Iw9xYDscC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Cross+of+Lead%22+Crispin&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtstvH7ZfbAhVLxFQKHadyDqkQ6AEIODAD#v=onepage&q=tonsure&f=false): "**Tonsure:** the part of the cleric's head, usually the crown, left bare by shaving". The book does include one instance of the word _pate_, as well.

Answer (score 144):

The 'crown' is the top of the head.

> The crown is the top of the head, or the whole head.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_(anatomy))

> The top part of the skull; the top of the head.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/45059?rskey=uOGsEB&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> the top part of a head

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crown)

> From toe to crown he'll fill our skins with pinches,

[Shakespeare - The Tempest IV, 1 - 1,972](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-results.php?link=con&searchtype=exact&works[]=tempest&keyword1=crown&sortby=WorkName&pleasewait=1&msg=sr)

=================================================================

Citation from 1535 :

> So wente Sathan forth from the LORDE, and smote Iob with maruelous sore byles, **from the sole off the fote vnto his crowne:**

[The Coverdale Bible](http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/18002007)

Comment: ...Jack fell down and broke his **crown**...and Jill came tumbling after :-)

Comment: I guess Jack will be making a trip to the dentist?

Comment: From [Criteria for accepting passport photos in Dutch travel documents](https://www.government.nl/documents/leaflets/2015/01/21/photomatrix-guidelines-2007): *Height: from age 11: from chin to crown, between 26 and 30 mm.
up to age 11: from chin to crown, between 19 and 30 mm*

Comment: By the way...that "v" is actually a *u*.  It's how it's been written since Latin until some versions ago of English... my brain gets frazzled trying to remember which one specifically.

Comment: (From the disappeared ventilator) But then a viewer does not necessarily view. A runner does not necessarily run. Bleachers tend to seat people. And benders leave people flat out. English does not pattern consistently/logically. A hamburger contains beef. Misnomers are a fact of life.

Answer (score 94):

[image: dictionary definition of PATE, reading "**pāte,** *n.* [ME.; prob. orig. euphemistic.] **1.** the head. **2**. the top of the head. **3.** intelligence. **4.** the skin of a calf's head. A humorous or derogatory term." The entire definition is circled in blue ink, with a red ink arrow pointing to the header "pāte" and another pointing to sub-definition 2. "the top of the head."]
Image from *Webster's* dictionary text which states the following:

> pate, n. [ME.; prob. orig. euphemistic.]
>
> 2. the top of the head.

*Vocabulary.com*:

> Your [**pate**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/pate) is the top of your head...

Comment: +1 "Fat paunches have lean pates, and dainty bits / Make rich the ribs, but bankrupt quite the wits." (Shakespeare)

Comment: ..And this seems to be the word the OP saw in the book he read according to [Paul's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/447066/156229).

Comment: I don't understand why/how this would be euphemistic.

Comment: @MissMonicaE you would need to look at its etymology to understand. In Latin, the word *patina* meant "shallow pan" or "dish".

Comment: As is often the case for the English language, we have more than one correct answer.  Pate and crown are both correct.

Comment: It is very much more archaic than ‘crown’ — which I would not consider so much archaic as antiquated, — and certainly obscure — I came here to answer with both ‘crown’ and ‘cap’, — but perhaps the aforementioned story of the original question would be intended for an audience who would recognize and even laud such a word as ‘pate’.  But, it is difficult to see whether @smci was addressing this answer or a previous comment.

Comment: "Pate" survives, I think, only in "bald pate" which is the area of your head targeted by hair regrowth scammers.

Comment: @smci ~ https://sobadsogood.com/2014/09/25/13-things-we-say-today-which-we-owe-to-shakespeare/ ~ 12 COMMON PHRASES WHICH WE OWE TO SHAKESPEARE ~ Some of us harbor no ill feelings toward Shakespeare, or to any of our ancestors.

Answer (score 33):

The sentence in the book you referenced "Crispin: The Cross of Lead", is this:

> With a sweep of his hand, he snatched off his hat, revealing a bald **pate**.

From the [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pate),

> #### pate
>
> = the top of a person's head

Answer (score 16):

There is also [scalp](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalp). Usually refers specifically to the skin, but not exclusively.

Answer (score 5):

In medical jargon, *vertex* is the top of the skull/ head.

*Crown* is used for reference to fetuses in the womb. For example:

> crown-rump length or length of the unborn fetus measured during an ultrasound.

Comment: But "reference to fetus's _what?_"... I need to know. I'm on tenterhooks to find out!

Comment: @NigelTouch - corrected

Comment: @NigelTouch: this is why I'll never spend to much time here, its full of pedants who's only goal seems to be looking clever. Kudos for you're comment however, it's construction is flawless :-)

Answer (score 4):

A [tonsure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonsure) is both the name of certain holy orders' haircut style, as well as the exposed top of the head resulting from that haircut.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it was fontanelle? That is where the 'soft spot' in a babies skull is located.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to be somewhat novel with language — cf. etymology of ‘suspicious’ anywhere but Wiktionary, where it is seriously deficient, — then you could consider

> cap

In most dialects which I've encountered, a ‘cap’ is any style of shallow hat.  Most etymological histories surmise a derivation from various words which are paronymic with the Latin ‘[caput](https://wiktionary.org/wiki/caput#Latin)’ i.e. ‘head’.

*Viz. e.g.*

> the cap of your head.

If your story occurs in the future, it may be a good way to suggest mutation of language while not being all too indecipherable.